# Why should setting attributes using jQuery give any different results than that from setting using DOM methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am changing the position of an input field in my javascript on a certain action. If I use jQuery to change the position, it just doesn't work, even though I can see the attributes for that input field updated to required values in the browser source.
However, if I set the style using plain javascript, it just works fine.
Can anyone point out what exactly is the difference between the following blocks?

```
        document.getElementById('prompt').style.left = X;
        document.getElementById('prompt').style.top = Y;
        document.getElementById('prompt').style.position = 'absolute'

        $('#prompt').attr("left",X);
        $('#prompt').attr("top",Y);
        $('#prompt').attr("position","absolute");
```

I am running this on chrome Version 32.0.1700.102 m

Comment: Those are CSS properties, not HTML attributes, so you want `.css`, not `.attr`

Comment: Then use plain javascript. It's not that bad. ;)

Comment: @elclanrs You should really make your comment an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are CSS properties, not HTML attributes, so you need to use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/), not [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('#prompt').css({left: X, top: Y, position: 'absolute'})
```